# Retrieve variable value set in each loop, outside of the loop

Tags: jquery

I need to get the value of a variable that's set in an `each` loop in jQuery. Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#conservatory_size .eva_toggle').each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
     var conservatory_size_total = $(this).data('price');
  }
});
alert(conservatory_size_total);
```

The value is there and it works, because if I call the alert inside the `each` loop it shows the correct price. But out of the loop the variable doesn't even alert.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

If I do what you have said, the IF statement is blatantly working, declaring the variable before the loop.. is not.

```
$('#conservatory_size .eva_toggle').each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                var conservatory_size_total = $(this).data('price');
                alert('Has class.');
            }
        });
        alert(conservatory_size_total);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable outside the loop:

```
var conservatory_size_total = '';
$('#conservatory_size .eva_toggle').each(function(){...
```

Comment: The value is empty.

Comment: Please see my updated question, definitely not that.

Comment: Ahhh! I was doing it wrong. Thank you. Have marked this as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your var outside the loop

```
var conservatory_size_total;
$('#conservatory_size .eva_toggle').each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
     conservatory_size_total = $(this).data('price');
  }
});
alert(conservatory_size_total);
```

Comment: It just says 'undefined'.